# Por que esse Css não funciona?

Tags: html, css3

eu tenho algumas dúvidas neste código. Eu gostaria de usar fonte open sans no texto, que o texto fosse alinhado para cima na tabela. Sabem dizer pq o css nao funciona aplicado ao html? Lembrando que a outra td da tabela tem imagens uma em cima da outra que esticam a coluna.

```
<td>
<div  class = "coluna_meio">
<p class = "texto"> 
texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto textotexto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto textotexto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto textotexto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto textotexto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto textotexto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto texto
                    </p>
                </div>
            </td>
```

css:

```
.texto {
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left:30px; 
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Reformate sua pergunta e deixe seu problema mais claro por favor, assim poderemos lhe ajudar!

Comment: Você só consegue visualizar uma fonte em um site, se aquela fonte (um arquivo de extensão .ttf) estiver salva no seu computador. Do jeito que font-family na classe texto está definido quer dizer que se no seu computador não tiver "Open Sans" instalado o texto vai ser com sans-serif e se esta tb não estiver instalada ai vai ser apresentado na font default do navegador. Faça o que Thiago Custodio recomenda que seu texto vai funfar!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa importar a fonte antes de usá-la:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Insira no topo de seu css o @import url que problema vai ser resolvido

Veja o exemplo:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');

.texto {
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left:30px; 
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```